# How can we map training data to 0 to 1 for Theano?

Tags: python, numpy, theano

As you might know for training task in Theano we have to map our training data to 0 to 1. My training data has negative values also. Currently I am using this formula:

x'=(x - min(x))/(max(x) - min(x))

which is implemented by this code:

```
for i in range (train_x.shape[0]):
    train_x[i,:] = ((train_x[i,:] - train_x[i,:].min(0)) /train_x[i,:].ptp(0))
```

Is this formula correct? Do you have a better idea regarding feature rescaling?

Comment: Are those numpy arrays?  About 10 minutes ago, I wrote:  `(x - x.min(axis=0)) / x.ptp(axis=0)` which looks almost identical to what you have (sans the loop).  It seems to me that you will only be normalizing within a single row, not across rows as you probably want to be doing.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, they are numpy arrays. And you're right. I am concerning about the fact that in this situation, I will have one 0 and one 1 in every row. How can we normalize across all rows?

Comment: I think that you should be able to use the expression in my first comment (substitute `train_x` for `x`).  No loop should be necessary.

Comment: I tried your comment and it is not working. These are the results:train_set_x= [[ 7.6990701   2.17705725 -3.49150865 ..., -0.33457212  1.02\
0639
  -0.52406797]
 [-1.50598435  0.52384467 -1.92651141 ..., -1.12350943  0.05220407
  -0.06458882]
 [ 6.70513488  0.36322057 -1.53669312 ..., -1.59078881 -0.51936011
   0.29170968]
 ...,
 [ 6.92596268  2.02438224 -3.15645995 ...,  0.23745564  1.52109066
  -0.72535945]
 [ 6.00661444  1.44427386 -2.22867013 ..., -0.13492791 -0.95444645
   0.51398081]
 [-6.28165553  0.07711241  0.52136293 ...,  0.36748433  0.51728437
   0.1107671 ]]

Answer (score 0):

so this is my way to do normalization for variable `t` use your formula:

```
import numpy as np
t = np.array([[-1,-2,3,2],[2,1,3,-1]],dtype='float32')
b = (t-t.min(1).reshape(2,1))/t.ptp(1).reshape(2,1)
print b
```

it gives the correct output:

```
[[0.2, 0,   1, 0.8]
[0.75, 0.5, 1,   0]]
```